# React hooks: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

I've looked at other answers to questions, but haven't been able to find one that's entirely related as I think my issue has something to do with dev dependencies, but I am willing to be wrong about this.

I'm using Gutenberg and building a block with `React v 16.12.0`. The specific functionality is to let the user choose the number of posts to display per page, then give a pagination functionality underneath which cycles through the posts determined by the posts per page.

The problem is that when I use the code listed below, I get the following error:

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

This in turn links to [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) article.

My code is as follows:

**PostsContainer.js**

```
const API = "http://localhost/wp-engine/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100";

const PostsContainer = props => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(props.numPosts);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(API);
      setPosts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  //Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

  //Change page
  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  console.log(posts);

  return (
    <>
      <Posts posts={currentPosts} loading={loading} />
      {/* {props.paginatePosts && <Pagination />} */}
      <Pagination
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={posts.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default PostsContainer;
```

**Pagination.js**

```
const Pagination = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {pageNumbers.map(number => {
        return (
          <li key={number}>
            <a onClick={() => paginate(number)} href="#">
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

**Posts.js**

```
const Posts = ({ posts, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <Post
            image={post.dp_post_featured_image}
            title={post.title.rendered}
            content={post.excerpt.rendered}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Now, I don't think it's the code (I could be wrong and please point out if I am). I think this is related to the 3rd criteria of this problem from [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) think again which says:

> Duplicate React In order for Hooks to work, the react import from your
>   application code needs to resolve to the same module as the react
>   import from inside the react-dom package.

It says to run `npm ls react` to check for duplicate react, which I do, and get the following:

```
+-- @wordpress/scripts@6.0.0
| `-- @wordpress/babel-preset-default@4.7.0
|   `-- @wordpress/element@2.9.0
|     `-- react@16.12.0  deduped <--Is this the issue?
`-- react@16.12.0
```

also ran `npm ls react-dom` and got something similar:

```
+-- @wordpress/scripts@6.0.0
| `-- @wordpress/babel-preset-default@4.7.0
|   `-- @wordpress/element@2.9.0
|     `-- react-dom@16.12.0  deduped
`-- react-dom@16.12.0
```

So is the issue that `react` has duplicate installs? Or is it my code?

Either way, any ideas how to fix it or should I just use a class component to manage what I'm trying to do instead? I'd rather use hooks, as it is much cleaner, but obviously class will do if need be.

Comment: What version of `react-dom` are you using?

Comment: 16.12.0, I'll update the question to reflect this

Comment: It looks like you are developing for WordPress. The Gutenberg editor scripts already ship with react, so in your script you shouldnt include it. Actually, you dont need to include any of the @wordpress packages in your scripts, they are all available inside the editor. For example: @wordpress/blockEditor -> wp.blockEditor. It seems like the issue you are facing is that you are including React in your script, so it creates a conflict with the already available copy.

Comment: Yeah I got that I didn’t install react though the only thing I installed was WordPress scripts: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-scripts/